# My Time machine partition disappeared on my WD MyBookWorld NAS

Tags: nas, time-machine

Several month ago I bought WD MyBookWorld 1TO NAS.

After upgrading the firmware to the last version, I was able to configure time machine.
On the left pane of the finder window, under the "Shared" category, I could see 2 drives :

- MyBookWorld : where I stored my data
- MyBookWorld (WD_Backup) : used by time machine

The time machine backup was running quite fine, even if sometimes it was delayed (due to my network deconnection I guess).

One day the backup did'nt worked anymore: the second drive disapeared (meanwhile the first is still accessible and functional).

If you have an idea why I'm interested!

Comment: Did you ever [solve this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/82486/how-do-i-answer-my-own-question-on-stack-overflow)?

Comment: No I bring it back to the shop I bought it and get cash back to buy a timecapsule. Shall I close this question? How?

Comment: This being a Q&A site, not some forum, you cannot close questions when they're no longer relevant. But as this seems to be quite localised to only your situation, and as there's no relevant answer, you could delete it. (Don't delete too many questions though; see [Should I avoid deleting my questions?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86982/should-i-avoid-deleting-my-questions/87029#87029))

Comment: The thing is that it is still valuable information for someone wanting to use WD MyBookWorld with timemachine so I don't want to delete it. I don't care the answer never because I don't have this device anymore.

Comment: Very well. I don't see any value (and whoever runs into the same issue in the future might see their question closed as a duplicate of this one, without much detail), but surely you could leave it here.

Answer (score 0):

The second partition may have become corrupted, or unmounted. I don't know enough about your NAS model, but if you have some admin interface or otherwise a location to view logs, some of that output might help us.

Did you try turning it off and on again?

Comment: Did you watch "the IT Crowd"? :D